# find files in current directory

Tags: shell

I have a txt file with some current directory names

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

and here's my all file in directory

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
...
```

I need to find files from txt file and remove files from my current directory. How I need to do that?

```
grep -l "(cat file.txt)" `ls`
```

this doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you make your question more clearly? `grep` is not used for finding files.

Comment: I update my question.

Comment: `xargs rm -f -- < file.txt` ?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This breaks if `file.txt` contains filenames with spaces.  Safer version: `tr '\n' '\0' <file.txt | xargs -0 rm -f --`.

Comment: @lcd047, the OP didn't fully specify the exact format of `file.txt`. `xargs rm -f -- < file.txt` can handle file names with spaces or even newline (while `xargs -d '\n'` or your `tr|-0` can't) provided `file.txt` is in the right format.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Try this: `touch a b 'a b' ; echo 'a b' >list; xargs rm -f -- <list ; ls -1`.

Comment: @lcd047, that's the wrong format. For that file, you need `file.txt` to contain `'a b'` or `a\ b` or `a" "b`... That's why I said _provided it's in the right format_. Note that blanks and newline are not the only characters to quote. The quoting characters themselves also need quoted.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The first blockquote in the question shows the filenames are supposed to be one per line.  This rules out newlines in filenames (and frankly, in ~30 years of working with computers, I have yet to see a real world case of file with newlines in its name).  And the `tr ... -0` elliminates the need to quoting anything.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, then this one liner should do:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r file; do rm -- "$file"; done <file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs`:

```
xargs rm -rf -- <file.txt
```

Comment: This breaks if `file.txt` contains filenames with spaces. Safer version: `tr '\n' '\0' <file.txt | xargs -0 rm -f --`.  Also, `-r` is a potantial hazard there. :)

Comment: @lcd047, the OP didn't fully specify the exact format of `file.txt`. `xargs rm -f -- < file.txt` can handle file names with spaces or even newline (while `xargs -d '\n'` or your `tr|-0` can't) provided `file.txt` is in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to find files of a certain type from within a directory. I'd recommend the 'find' command for this.

First, to find files with the .txt extension from within a directory:

find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*.txt" -print

If you're satisfied with your search results, you can then remove these files with :

find /path/to/directory -type -f -name "*.txt" -delete

Cheers!